# why am i getting undefined error from input value?

Tags: javascript

so, when i console.log document.getElementById("deposit-amount").value I get real time numbers/data. But when I put it into variable and console.log the name (depositAmount), it shows undefined.

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="deposit">
      <h4>Deposit</h4>
      <input id="deposit-amount" type="number" placeholder="$ amount you want to deposit">
      <button id="deposit-btn">Deposit</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
const depositAmount = document.getElementById("deposit-amount").value;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: You're setting the variable when the page first loads, before the user has entered anything into the input.

Comment: But in that case it should set the variable to an empty string, not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine in this snippet. Is there any more code you can share to debug?

```js
function log() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('deposit-amount').value);
}
```

```html
<div class="deposit">
  <h4>Deposit</h4>
  <input id="deposit-amount" type="number" placeholder="$ amount you want to deposit">
  <button id="deposit-btn" onclick="log()">Deposit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If he doesn it when the DOM isn't ready, it will get an error, not set the variable to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box-1 common-box">
   <p>Deposit</p>
    <h2>$ <span id="current-deposit">01</span></h2>
 </div>
<div class="deposit">
       <h4>Deposit</h4>
         <input id="deposit-amount" type="number"  placeholder="$ amount you want to deposit">
           <button id="deposit-btn">Deposit</button>
</div>
```

```
const depositBtn = document.getElementById("deposit-btn");
depositBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const depositAmount = document.getElementById("deposit-amount").value; 
    const depositNumber = parseFloat(depositAmount);
    const cuurentDeposit = document.getElementById("current-deposit").innerText;
    const currentNumber = parseFloat(cuurentDeposit);
    const total = depositNumber + currentNumber; 
    document.getElementById("current-deposit").innerText = total;
    document.getElementById("deposit-amount").value = "";

})
```

This works. but still when I console.log the name (depositAmount), it shows undefined.Is this because  DOM isn't ready? How to resolve this?  -@nemo